# What's the correct syntax for tcp.dstport in display filters

Tags: wireshark

I've put the following display filter:

```
tcp.dstport=8127
```

But it's showing as incorrect (red background):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your edit changed your question completely, rendering the answer invalid. Don't do that, ask a new question instead if a new one arises.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, yeah, sorry about that, but I've edited to show the original question and so the answer by **Hangin on in quiet desperation** is still relevant.

Comment: I have rolled this back to it's original version. If you want to ask an entirely different question then do just that by asking a new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use `==` rather than `=`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) and some [examples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).

Comment: thanks, yeah, just found that myself. What's the difference between `eq` and `==`? And is `=` illegal in display filters.

Comment: I have no idea, I just did a quick google for you. Perhaps if you actually read the links I posted ...

Comment: AFAIK, it comes from C programming.  The = operator assigns a value (`j=3`), while the == operator compares a value (`if j==3`).  Annoyingly, you can also write `if j=3`, and it's syntactically legal, but *always* true (unless for some reason assigning the value 3 to the variable j fails).

Comment: @MadHatter, thanks a lot for you feedback! Best of luck

Comment: @MadHatter: `if j=3` is not legal C; `if(j=3)` with the parentheses (plus whitespace as desired) is legal and usually wrong. Many compilers warn for this, at least if you crank up the settings; in the rare case you do want it, usually you can use _extra_ parentheses `if((j=3))` to suppress the warning. Fun, eh?